# Modifying Char array passed to function

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a function and I want to modify `cardString[]` that is passed to it so that `cardString[]` contains `[charSuit, cardRank, '\0']`:

```
void getCard(int row, int column, char cardString[]){
    PlayingCard myCard = myDeck.cardArray[row][column];
    char charSuit;
    char charRank;   

    if (myCard.getSuit() == CLUB)
        charSuit = 'C';
    else if (myCard.getSuit() == SPADE)
        charSuit = 'S';
    else if (myCard.getSuit() == HEART)
        charSuit = 'H';
    else if (myCard.getSuit() == DIAMOND)
        charSuit = 'D';
    if (myCard.getRank() == NINE)
        charRank = '9';
    else if (myCard.getRank() == TEN)
        charRank = 'T';
    else if (myCard.getRank() == JACK)
        charRank = 'J';
    else if (myCard.getRank() == QUEEN)
        charRank = 'Q';
    else if (myCard.getRank() == KING)
        charRank = 'K';
    else if (myCard.getRank() == ACE)
        charRank = 'A';
}
```

Comment: I want to modify the char array that is passed to the function.

Comment: The char array is originally defined as charArray[3]=['\0','\0','\0']

Comment: @user1004358: it's really just a pointer, so you can write to it about like any other (pointer or array syntax).

Comment: so i add char *p; p=cardString; *p=charSuit+charRank; ?

Comment: `cardString` is an array of characters...what do you want to store in it?

Comment: I want to store the charSuit and charRank i get from the if statements followed by a null byte character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one-line way to assign an entire array; you need to write three assignment statements:

```
cardString[0] = charSuit;
cardString[1] = charRank;
cardString[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: but my function is a void function i want to change cardString in memory.

Comment: @user1004358: Yes, exactly. That's what the above statements will do. (Are you seeing some sort of problem?)